# command object has no attribute missingpermissions

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

I am writing an error handler with my discord bot and it was working well until I installed and imported youtube_dl and pynacl (which I am using to make it play music).

Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx,error):
    if isinstance(error,commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You do not have rights to this command.")
        await ctx.message.delete()
    elif isinstance(error,commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("You need an argument.")
        await ctx.message.delete()
    elif isinstance(error,commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send("Invalid Command.")
        await ctx.message.delete()
    else:
        raise error
```

error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hensd\bots\bot.py", line 127, in on_command_error
    if isinstance(error,commands.MissingPermissions):
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'MissingPermissions'
```

when I test the other possible error I get the same message with the corresponding errors instead of MissingPermissions\

EDIT:  The reason this happened is because I created a command called "commands"
which basically showed the commands and what they do.  python thought that I was trying to import "commands" from there.  All I had to do was rename the command so python was not confused between the two.  thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Does anyone know if I actually need pynacl or youtube_dl to play music?   I am just watching a youtube tutorial

Comment: How did you import `commands`?

Comment: import discord

from discord.ext import commands

import random

import youtube_dl

import praw

Comment: i have a new line before each import i just don't know how to comment a new line

Comment: Can you show the whole code? A wrong value has to be assigned to `commands` somewhere

Comment: character limit i cant -_-

Comment: here i can link a google doc

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_YeXMaYxW4QfVqOARWviP2TTifgl-a6MjzfsAwK_dYg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you. I don't get any error when adding the piece of code in the question to my bot and also can't find out what's wrong with the code in the doc.

Comment: if it helps, I think it is looking in client.py instead of core.py

Comment: What is client.py and what is core.py?

Comment: core.py is in
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands

and client.py is in  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\discord

I imported "commands" from discord ext as seen in code but something is making it look in client.py